# Parity of a Permutation and Shifting

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given a permutation $P$ of $[1,2,...,n]$ and a positive integer $t\le n$. An operation is defined as shifting any $t$ consecutive elements of $P$ cyclically to the right by one index. For example: given $\pi(P)=[2,1,3,4]$ and $t=3$ we can perform an operation on the last $3$ elements to obtain $[2,4,1,3]$. We perform another operation on the first $3$ elements to obtain $[1,2,4,3]$.

Is there a way to determine if a certain permutation can be reached from the given permutation by applying finite number operations? I've heard that it has something to with the parity of the permutations, but can't actually figure out. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any permutation can be decomposed into cycles and each cyclic permutation can be decomposed into transpositions. Of course, this decomposition is not necessarily *unique* but the parity of the number of transpositions is. Two permutations are reachable iff they have the same parity.

Comment: For instance, a cyclic permutation of $k$ elements is even iff $k$ is odd. Hence, by applying such transformations with odd $k$ (you take $k=3$ in your example), you can only reach permutations that have the same parity. (as a side note, for an application of this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle)

Comment: Sorry I might be catching slow... But if the given is $[4,2,1,5,3]$ (odd) and $t=4$, we can reach $[5,4,2,1,3]$ (even) by applying shift on first $4$ elements. They have different parities.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani please clarify a bit. I'm a beginner. :/

Comment: Simply Google those terms that you don't know!

Comment: I did. But I didn't understand your last sentence "Two permutations are reachable iff they have the same parity".

Comment: Does that mean we can reach permutation $Q$ from $P$ by applying some $k$-shifts for any given $k$ iff the parity of transposition numbers of $P$ and $Q$ are same? That isn't true.